# Does God love us?

Tags: scripture, gods, guru, love

This seems like a rather rhetorical question to ask. But this question has been in my mind since I saw a video of Yogi and Mystic Jaggi Vasudev. Guru Jaggi Vasudev is sometimes really confusing for me and is the only spiritual teacher till now that I have seen who sometimes speaks completely opposite of what you would hear from other great spiritual masters and philosophers. An example would be [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyMXTPlyPgc) in which he clearly states and I quote,

> [If you say God loves me, you should know that you are a pathetic, despicable case.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyMXTPlyPgc#t=02m07s)" and "[It (the source of creation) has no love, it has no compassion, it has no intention of helping you, it has no intention of harming you, it has nothing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kyMXTPlyPgc#t=03m09s)

And never have I heard in any of Guru Jaggi Vasudev's videos that God is always with you or God will help you in your difficult situations or anything like that which other famous spiritual personalities have said. He even in some of his videos vaguely seems to say that there is no God. Or at least that's what I think.

---

So to sum it up, the specific questions that I need answers to are stated below.

1. **Does God love us?**
2. **Does God help us in difficult situations?**

Also, please present any scriptural references about love of God for us and if God helps us if there are any. That will greatly help!

Comment: Good question. However, '3: Why does Guru Jaggi Vasudev claim such things?' is not valid for the site so I've edited it out. For more info, see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Dont listen to self-styled "gurus" who are not very literate.

Comment: God is our eternal father/mother both. He loves us more than anybody else.

Comment: Btw, I don't find Sadhguru JV wrong here. He is saying in different context. Rather, seems attacking Abrahmic religions.

Comment: God (Brahman) does not love. God is Love. If you had to sum up God in one word it is Love. God (Brahman) does not help us in difficult situations, that is where saints and gods come in. If you want help in your life pray to the gods and the saints. They can help. God does not.

Comment: @sv. All right. Thank you for refining this question brother! :)

Comment: @moonstar2001 Well... it may be possible that I may have failed to understand the context. But either way if it is written in the Bhagvad Gita that the Ultimate Reality loves and helps us then that's what it is.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Your sentence makes sense brother. Thank you for sharing your thoughts with me! :)

Comment: @Rohit Maybe it's possible. But that doesn't seem to explain why Guru Jaggi Vasudev would not use the word "God" and always emphasize that Gods are our creation.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda But two gentlemen below have presented verses from the Bhagvad Gita and the Kurma Purana where the Ultimate Reality (Brahman) Himself says that He loves his devotees especially those who seek knowledge and also helps us in difficult situations if we meditate upon Him. How is that?

Comment: Nirguna Brahman is undivided Consciousness and has no awareness of the world of multiplicity. When Krishna speaks in the Gita he is speaking as Saguna Brahman, Brahman perceived through the veil of Maya. Saguna Brahman is Isvara. We cannot pray to Nirguna Brahman, we can only pray to Saguna Brahman. Pray to Saguna Brahman for Liberation. Asking Saguna Brahman for helps in our petty lives is like begging a merchant in diamonds for glass beads. Look at Arjuna. He had Krishna Himself for his friend and companion and still had nothing but troubles all his life.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Sir well, I've not answered based on AV. I don't believe Brahman is inert & impotent to create, though I believe in non duality.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Yes God loves. Both Sagun & Nīrguna if I talk based on the system I follow.

Comment: He is speaking in advaitic terms she how delusion this so called guru is if you follow advaitic practice you will also speak such nonsense in future

Comment: god is inside you so if you love god he will love you back more times.. if you love gods devotee he will love even more so which is your god and guru, one should get proper guru deksha..

Comment: Sadhguru is not an authority on Hinduism. Take the words of businesspeople gurus like him with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1- Yes, God loves.**

> The virtuous ones who worship me are of four kinds, the distressed, the seeker of knowledge, the seeker of wealth, and the man of knowledge, O Lord of the Bharatas. (**BG 7.16**)
> Of these, the man of knowledge, who is permanently established in yoga, whose devotion is single-minded, is **the best. For I'm dear to him and he is** *exceedingly* **dear to me**. (**BG 7.17**)

Thus, it is clearly explained man of knowledge is very **dear** to God. 
Further, Krishna says in the next verse-

> Noble indeed are all of these, but the man of knowledge I consider to be **My very self**. For, with an integrated self he resorts to me alone as the highest goal.

Thus, it is clearly explained by the ultimate reality, the extent of his love to the man of knowledge which he expressed calling him his very **self.** He although loves everyone but he exceptionally love the man of knowledge. 
The same union or immense love between God & devotee (man of knowledge) is expressed again in the BG 9.30.

> I'm the same in all beings. None I hate nor **particularly** like. But those who worship Me with devotion, they stand in Me & I also in them (particularly like).

**2- Yes, he protects as well.**
Lord Krishna, the ultimate reality says in Bhagvat Geeta chapter 18, verse 58.

> Fixing your mind on me, you will, by My grace, **cross over all difficulties;** but if, through the sense of egoism, you will not listen, you will perish.

Thus, Krishna clearly says he helps us to cross over all difficulties through **his grace.** And grace can be gotten by fixing our mind on the ultimate reality.

Comment: Thank you very much for bringing this knowledge in light for me brother! It may be possible that I must've failed to understand what Guru Jaggi Vasudev was actually trying to say. But either way, if it's written in the Bhagvad Gita that God loves us and protects us then it must be true. Thank you very much again for your help! :)

Comment: Welcome @PradeepKumar :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes,God both protect us and love us too.

So,I don't know why Guru Jaggi Vasudev said what he said.May be we have failed to understand the context.

Anyway, in  [Kurma Purana](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=18);

Parama Shiva says:

> Adveshata Sarva bhutaanaam maitrah Karuna yevacha,
>
> Nirmomaa nirahankaaro yo madbhaktah sa mey Priyah/
>
> Santhushtah Satatam Yogi yatatatmaa drudha nischayah,
>
> Mayyarpitamano buddhiryo madhaktah sa mey priyah/
>
> Yasmaannuddejito loko Lokaannujjeto cha yah,
>
> Harshaamarsha bhayodvegairmukto yah sa hi mey priyah/
>
> Anapekshah Shuchirdaksha udaaseeno gatvyathah,
>
> Sarvaarambha parityaagi Bhaktimaan yah sada mey priyah/
>
> **Meaning**
>
> Those Bhaktaas who treat every Being without malice, hatred, and
>   self-pride; but with friendliness, kindness and affection **are dear to
>   me;** those who are contented, self-controlled, strong willed,
>   ever-engaged in Yoga and totally dedicated to me **are dear to me**; those
>   who neither get excited nor prone to exciting others, but are
>   fearless, placid and composed **are dear to me**; those who never crave
>   for worldly desires, but are ready to sacrifice, are impartial, are
>   ready to face challenges of the right kindand are not non-starters due
>   to hesitation **are indeed near and dear to me**

Similarly He gives [assurance of protection](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=16) to devotees as follows:

> Na madbhaktaa vinashyanti madbhaktaa veeta kalmashaah,
>
> Aadaavetat pratigjaanam na mey bhaktah pranashyati/
>
> Patram Pushpam Phalam toyam madaaraadhana kaaranaat,
>
> Yo mey dadaati niyatah sa meyBhaktah Priyomatah
>
> **Meaning**
>
> **My Bhaktaas would never be destroyed nor harmed but would be washed off their sins as I took a vow that my Bhaktas are protected**.
>   Bhaktas are merely required to perform my Puja with utmost sincerity
>   and offer leaves, flowers, fruits and even water as I would be
>   pleased.

And, God also helps us in getting rid of difficult situations too.There is a famous stotram dedicated to Goddess Durga named [Sri Durga Apad Uddharaka Stotram](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durga-a8.html?lang=sa) which literally means the stotram that relieves us from Apada or dangers or emergencies.

Comment: It may be possible that I was not able to comprehend what Guru Jaggi Vasudev was saying. But it's written in the Kurma Mahapurana that the Ultimate Reality loves us and protects us if we meditate upon Him. Then it has to be true. Thank you very much for your help brother! This knowledge really helps me in understanding the Truth! :)